# Not able to receive the broadcast from an Activity

Tags: android, broadcast

I think everything is perfect in the code but I'm not able to receive the broadcast in the broadcast receiver.

Here is my ACTIVITY

```
public class BroadcastDemo extends Activity {
Button bt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent broadint = new Intent();
            broadint.setAction("SENT_BROADCAST");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadint);
            Log.e("Dillu","BroadCast is sent");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is Broadcast Receiver

```
public class ReceiveBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context con,Intent inte){
    Log.e("Dillu","Receiving the BroadCast");
    if(inte.getAction().equals("SENT_BROADCAST"))
        Toast.makeText(con, "Received BroadCast Succesfully",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Dillu","Received the BroadCast");
}
```

}

Here is the Receiver registered in the Manifest file

```
<Receiver
        android:name=".ReceiveBroadcast">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SENT_BROADCAST"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </Receiver>
```

The Broadcast receiver is not able to receive the Broadcast sent from Activity. I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: have you set required permissions?

Comment: @Stuti - Both Activity and Broadcast Receiver are in the same application.What permissions i am supposed to keep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this would resolve your question, but I can see that your tag has capital "R"

`<Receiver>` tag should be `<receiver>`

Comment: Thank you very much frnd. Its working fine now.Writing R instead of r is a very big mistake.